# How to typeset hyphenated words using Zellman font?

Tags: fonts, hyphenation

Zellman font apparently drops hyphens:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\normalfont\initfamily
\fontsize{6mm}{6mm}\selectfont Multi-Scale
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any work-around to compensate this case?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the [link1](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/zallmancaps/) of your code:

```
\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
```

and there is written that **Zallman Caps exists in uppercase only**. Also into the [link2](https://www.1001fonts.com/zallman-caps-font.html#character-map) (label character map `.ttf`) there is not any `-` symbol. Just an improved by comment of **@egreg** using `.5em` instead of `.01\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\normalfont\initfamily
\fontsize{6mm}{6mm}\selectfont Multi\rule[.7ex]{.5em}{.1pt}Scale
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\textwidth`? Maybe something like `0.5em` would be better.

Comment: You're right. I have seen the guide of the rule similar when you put a picture into tex file. Now edit my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm wondering whether it is straightforward to add some drawing around the hyphen just like the other letters. The hyphen seems relatively naked, however I understand that drawing stuff would be tough to be realised as something relates to the design of the font.

Comment: @Roboticist Hi, I can propose to you to use `pgfornaments`, or `adforn` packages, but I have tried in vain to find something with flowers but I have not found anything. I'm sorry.

Comment: My idea was to remove the code with `\textwidth` altogether.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much....done!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an ugly line which neither matches the weight of the font or the design, how about borrowing something from the font?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\normalfont\initfamily
\fontsize{6mm}{6mm}\selectfont Multi\raisebox{0.2ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.5}{I}}}Scale
\end{document}
```

(size and position to be adjusted to taste)

Comment: But the line is really ugly? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano From all my heart: yes, very ugly because it does not match the font

Comment: Such an interesting idea `:-)` +1.